# Cant get jQuery hover to work with an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-hover

I have a row of custom styled radio buttons. On hover, I want a sort icon (two arrows made with css) to appear. I've gotten this to work successfully with jQuery's `.hover` function. However, when I try to add some logic to only allow the sort arrow to appear when a radio button is NOT checked, the hover event does not work. There's obviously a problem with the if statement; I suspect it's the syntax, but I'm just not sure how to fix it.

***JS***

```
// COLUMN HEADING ROLLOVER SORT BUTTONS //

    var wrap = "<div class='sortWrap'>";
    var sortUp = "<div class='sortIcon arrow-up'></div>";
    var sortDown = "<div class='sortIcon arrow-down'></div>";
    var combine = wrap + sortUp + sortDown + "</div>";

    $('input[type=radio]+label').hover(function() {
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        if (checked == false) {
            $(this).append(combine);
        };  
        }, function() { 
            $(this).children('.sortWrap').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Usually you're a lot better of hiding and showing an element instead of creating it and removing it on every hover event.

Comment: var is_checked = $(this).is(':checked');

Comment: Even if there are 15 radio buttons that all require rollovers?

Comment: Especially when there are many elements to create and remove on every hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).is(':checked')` or `this.checked`.

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

The other problem is that `this` in your handler is the `label` element, not the checkbox. You need `%(this).prev().is(':checked')`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/s8LM9/8/)

Comment: This still isn't making a difference. I'm only getting a problem when I add the if statement.

Comment: The problem isn't the `if` statement, it's the assignment to `checked`. I noticed this when I stepped through the code in the debugger, it was setting `checked` to `undefined`. That's when I realized you were trying to get the `checked` property of the `label`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had much better success with is(':checked') than I've had with prop('checked').

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. I had the default radio buttons set to hide in CSS so I could style custom buttons.